# Mobile networks: diffrence of mobile authentication algorith Milenage Version 1 & Version 2

Tags: authentication, gsm, sim-card

I've heard in the telecom industry about Milenage Version 1 algorithm and Milenage Version 2 algorithm.

I want to know what are their differences?

The version 1 and version 2 have the same length for K which is 128-bits (K is the key for authentication) but the differences are not known to me.

Can somebody please name the standard document for each of these versions? Inside the standards I could not find anything which defines version 2 or version 1.

P.S. [ETSI TS 135 206](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/135200_135299/135206/13.00.00_60/ts_135206v130000p.pdf) standard specifies details about Milenage algorithm. But I cannot pinpoint what is Version 1 and what is the version 2 and what are their difference?